# difference between jquery styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

which style is fastest? when would you use one over the other?

Type 1:

```
function makeMap(){
    getLatlong();
    draw();
}
function getLatlong(){ ... }
function draw(){ ... }
makeMap();
```

Type 2:

```
var map = {
    init: function(){ ... }
    getLatlong: function(){ ... }
    draw: function(){ ... }
}
$test = map.init()
```

Comment: Whatever fits seems like a good practice.

Comment: "Better" in terms of what? And what does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: sorry ... "better" means performance. new to coding ... i guess this is just javascript then huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better style is the one the best fits your solution.

In general, any time a '.' is used to reference a property, you get a performance hit; however, it may be so small it may not even matter.

As for speed, let's test it:

http://jsperf.com/compare-object-function-properties-vs-functions

In both Chrome and IE, a direct function call is generally faster than an object property reference for a function call.